# pandas read_csv is putting all values in one column and one row

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I've sought out an answer on multiple forums and YouTube but to no avail, sorry in advance if it is widely available and my keywords just weren't right.

I'm attempting to execute a simple `pandas.read_csv('.csv',sep=',')`. However, the output I'm receiving is not splitting the data out into multiple columns as I imagine it should.

I'm getting back all of my headers in one row, separated by commas. The same is true for each line item tied to the respective headers.

I've tried setting this data up in a dataframe, manipulating the headers, manually adding the headers with no success.

For better understanding I've copied and pasted from Ipython notebook of what I'm seeing:

```
In [15]:
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Dale\Desktop\ShpData\TrackerTW0.csv',sep=',')

Out[15]:
PurchaseOrderNumber,ShipmentFinalDestinationCity,TransferPointCity,POType,PlannedMode,ProgramType,FreightPaymentTerms,ContainerNumber,BL/AWB#,Mode,ShipmentFinalDestinationLocation,CarrierSCAC,Carrier,Forwarder,BrandDesc,POLCity,PODCity,InDCOutlookDate,InDCOriginalDate,AnticipatedShipDate,PlannedStockedDate,ExFactoryActualDate(LT),OriginConsolActualDate(LT),DepartLoadPortActualDate(LT),FullOutGatefromOceanTerminal(CYorPort)ActualDate(LT),DPArrivalActualDate(LT),FreightAvailableActualDate(LT),DestConsolActualDate(LT),DomDepartActualDate(LT),YardArrivalActualDate(LT),CarrierDropActualDate(LT),InDCActualDate(LT),StockedActualDate(LT),Vessel,VesselETADischargePortCity,DPArrivalOutlookDate,VesselETADischargePortActualDate(LT),FullOutGatefromOceanTerminal(CYorPort)OutlookDate,StockedOutlookDate,ShipmentLeg#,Metrics,TotalShippedQty

0   1251708,Rugby,Tuticorin,Initial Order,Ocean,Re...
1   1262597,Rugby,Hong Kong,Initial Order,Ocean,Re...
```

Thanks

Comment: You should show the input few rows here and the code so far you have written and what is your expected output

Comment: Thank you - my expected output is I simply want to see each "header" and  its associated data in separate columns for example under Purchase Order Number I want to see 1251708

Comment: For someone to help you they need to see few lines of inputs

Comment: Okay I see. In the csv file, which I'm figuring is the 'inputs' data you're referring to my data looks like this: 
Line1: PurchaseOrderNumber,ShipmentFinalDestinationCity,TransferPointCity,POType,PlannedMode,ProgramType,FreightPaymentTerms,ContainerNumber
Line2: 1262597,Rugby,Hong Kong,Initial Order,Ocean,Regular,Paid By

Comment: Can you upload sample of your data on some web-resource (like github, for example)?

Comment: Try removing the `sep=','` argument. The default separator is ',' but your file might actually be delimited with something else even though it is saved as a `.csv`. `pandas` will automatically detect the delimiter type if none is specified.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try this, you have like 40 columns.

```
import pandas as pd 


df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', names=['PurchaseOrderNumber','ShipmentFinalDestinationCity','TransferPointCity','POType','PlannedMode','ProgramType','FreightPaymentTerms','ContainerNumber','BL/AWB#','Mode','ShipmentFinalDestinationLocation','CarrierSCAC','Carrier','Forwarder','BrandDesc','POLCity','PODCity','InDCOutlookDate','InDCOriginalDate','AnticipatedShipDate','PlannedStockedDate','ExFactoryActualDate(LT)','OriginConsolActualDate(LT)','DepartLoadPortActualDate(LT)','FullOutGatefromOceanTerminal(CYorPort)ActualDate(LT)','DPArrivalActualDate(LT)','FreightAvailableActualDate(LT)','DestConsolActualDate(LT)','DomDepartActualDate(LT)','YardArrivalActualDate(LT)','CarrierDropActualDate(LT)','InDCActualDate(LT)','StockedActualDate(LT)','Vessel','VesselETADischargePortCity','DPArrivalOutlookDate','VesselETADischargePortActualDate(LT)','FullOutGatefromOceanTerminal(CYorPort)OutlookDate','StockedOutlookDate','ShipmentLeg#','Metrics','TotalShippedQty']

print df
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I wanna process a csv file, the code is like this:

```py
data = pd.read_csv(dir, sep=" ")
print(data)
```

the output also put all values in one row,
then I just use the default "sep" value, the problem has been solved.

```py
data = pd.read_csv(dir, sep=",")
```

the situation seems like different from which the asker raised,
but I hope it's helpful for some other friends like me,
and this is my first comment, I hope it's not too bad!

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer. If this is an answer, please provide more information.

Comment: Can you explain the cases in which this can help?

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the best option but it works!

Read the file as it is:

```
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
```

Get all the column names and assign them to a variable.

```
names= df.columns.str.split(',').tolist()
```

Split all the values by ','

```
df= df.iloc[:,0].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

Finally, assign 'names' to column names and that's it!

```
df.columns = names
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same issues. All of the columns were coming as one value. So the following worked for me.

```
df = pd.read_csv('/content/Reviews.csv',
                 sep=',',
                 error_bad_lines=False,
                 engine='python')
```